# nodelet: error: nullptr was not declared in this scope

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, nodelet

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to install the ros base from source following [this link](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Source), everyting works fine.

Then I download the package `nodelet` and all of its dependencies packages. However, when I compile all of packages with `catkin_make`, I get an error:

```
[ 75%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/nodeletlib.dir/src/loader.cpp.o
In file included from /root/system-full/tmp/install_isolated/include/class_loader/class_loader.hpp:46:0,
                 from /root/system-full/tmp/install_isolated/include/class_loader/multi_library_class_loader.hpp:42,
                 from /root/system-full/tmp/install_isolated/include/pluginlib/class_loader.hpp:38,
                 from /root/system-full/tmp/src/nodelet_core/nodelet/src/loader.cpp:34:
/root/system-full/tmp/install_isolated/include/class_loader/class_loader_core.hpp: In function ‘void class_loader::impl::registerPlugin(const string&, const string&)’:
/root/system-full/tmp/install_isolated/include/class_loader/class_loader_core.hpp:183:7: error: ‘nullptr’ was not declared in this scope
   if (nullptr == getCurrentlyActiveClassLoader()) {
```

I can compile the package `class_loader` without any error but when I try to compile the package `nodelet`, I will get the error above.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/292165/nodelet:-error:-nullptr-was-not-declared-in-this-scope/) by [bear234](https://answers.ros.org/users/22393/bear234/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2018-05-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Kinetic is "only" compatible with platforms with compilers supporting C++11 (see [REP-3](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#kinetic-kame-may-2016-may-2021)). `nullptr` was added in C++11.

The fact that you see that error implies that whatever platform your compiling on / for does not have C++11 support (or doesn't have it enabled).

You'll have to either enable C++11 support in your compiler, or if that is not possible change to a compiler that does support it.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-05-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bear234](https://answers.ros.org/users/22393/bear234/) on 2018-05-24**:
`gcc -v` shows me the version of gcc is 5.4. I think it does support c++11

**Comment by [bear234](https://answers.ros.org/users/22393/bear234/) on 2018-05-24**:
at lease, `g++ -std=c++11` can compile c++11 code on my machine.

**Comment by [bear234](https://answers.ros.org/users/22393/bear234/) on 2018-05-24**:
https://github.com/ros/nodelet_core/issues/76

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-25**:
I don't know why your particular platform doesn't have C++11 enabled by default. The `kinetic-devel` dev-job on the buildfarm doesn't show the same error and uses GCC5.4 as well: [log](http://build.ros.org/view/Kdev/job/Kdev__nodelet_core__ubuntu_xenial_amd64/lastBuild/consoleText).